# Javascript manipulating json issue

Tags: javascript

```
    [
         {
             "timing": [
                 {
                     "zone": 18.8
                 },
                 {
                     "zone": 17.06,
                 },
                 {
                     "zone": 16.6
                 },
             ]
         },
         {
             "timing": [
                 {
                     "zone": 12.6,
                 },
                 {
                     "zone": 14.6,
                 }
             ]
         },
         {
             "timing": [
                 {
                     "zone":19.06,

                 },{
                     "zone": 8.06,
                 }
             ]
         }
     ]
```

Here i am trying to work manipulate with one json data using javascript.

But, I am not able to think any approach how to achive that.

I am expecting below json. It give zone1, zone2, zone3 as per the zone any it will be dynamically

Please have a look to below json.

```
     [
         {
             "zone1": [18.8, 12.6, 19.06 ]
         },{
              "zone2": [17.06, 14.6,  8.06]
         }, {
             "zone3":[16.6]
         }
     ]
```

This is the output of json how it should look like.

Please have a look

Comment: I'd use array reduce method

Comment: Can you please answer it?

Comment: Okay, what have you tried so far? Instead of asking how to do it, show us what approach you took and where you're stuck

Comment: @soubhagyapradhan - SO expects you to at least try - given the reduce method as an option, write something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use reduce and forEach

- Loop through data, set OP's initial value as an object
- Loop through `timing` property of each element, check if the `zone + index + 1` exists in op or not, if exists push zone to that key else initialise new key

```js
let data = [{"timing": [{"zone": 18.8},{"zone": 17.06,},{"zone": 16.6},]},{"timing": [{"zone": 12.6,},{"zone": 14.6,}]},{"timing": [{"zone": 19.06,}, {"zone": 8.06,}]}]

let final = data.reduce((op, { timing }) => {
  timing.forEach(({ zone }, i) => {
    let key = `zone${ 1 + i }`
    op[key] = op[key] || []
    op[key].push(zone)
  })
  return op
}, {})

console.log(final)

// If you need final output to be array of object just use entries and map to build a desired output 
console.log(Object.entries(final).map(([k,v])=>({[k]:v})))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution

```js
var data = [{
    "timing": [{
        "zone": 18.8
      },
      {
        "zone": 17.06,
      },
      {
        "zone": 16.6
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "timing": [{
        "zone": 12.6,
      },
      {
        "zone": 14.6,
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "timing": [{
      "zone": 19.06,

    }, {
      "zone": 8.06,
    }]
  }
];

// Calculate the total number of zones
var totalZones = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  const currZones = data[i].timing.length;
  if (currZones > totalZones) totalZones = currZones;
}
console.log(totalZones);

// Create the final Array
var result = new Array(totalZones);
for (let i = 0; i < totalZones; i++) {
 result[i] = {
  zone: []
  }
}

// Populate the final array with values
for (let i = 0; i < totalZones; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
   let currTiming = data[j].timing[i];
    if (currTiming !== undefined) {
      let currZone = data[j].timing[i].zone;
      if (currZone !== undefined) {
        result[i].zone.push(currZone);
      }
    }
  }
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Gather all zone values into one array of array

2) Calculate max rows needed for zones

3) Have a simple for-loop till max rows and use `shift` and `push` methods.

```js
const data = [
  {
    timing: [
      {
        zone: 18.8
      },
      {
        zone: 17.06
      },
      {
        zone: 16.6
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    timing: [
      {
        zone: 12.6
      },
      {
        zone: 14.6
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    timing: [
      {
        zone: 19.06
      },
      {
        zone: 8.06
      }
    ]
  }
];

const zones = data.map(time => time.timing.map(z => z.zone));
const rows = zones.reduce((rows, arr) => Math.max(rows, arr.length), 0);

const all = [];
for (let index = 1; index <= rows; index++) {
  const res = [];
  zones.forEach(zone => zone.length > 0 && res.push(zone.shift()));
  all.push({ [`zone${index}`]: res });
}

console.log(all);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const input =     [ {"timing": [{"zone": 18.8},{"zone": 17.06,},{"zone": 16.6},]},{"timing": [{"zone": 12.6,},{"zone": 14.6,}]},{"timing": [{"zone":19.06,},{"zone": 8.06,}]}]
     
var data = input.map(t => t.timing.map(u => u.zone));
var output = data[0].map((col, i) => data.map(row => row[i])).map((item, index) => {res = {}; res["zone"+(index+1)] = item.filter(t => t!==undefined); return res});
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the shortest, but it's very readable.

```js
var json = [{"timing": [{"zone": 18.8},{"zone": 17.06,},{"zone": 16.6},]},{"timing": [{"zone": 12.6,},{"zone": 14.6,}]},{"timing": [{"zone": 19.06,}, {"zone": 8.06,}]}];

    
// index 0 is zone1, index 1 is zone2, index 2 is zone3, and so on ...
var zones = [];
    
// Loop through each 'timing' object
json.forEach(function(timingObject) {
  var timing = timingObject['timing'];

  // loop through each 'zone' in the given 'timing' object
  timing.forEach(function(zoneObject, index) {

    var zone = zoneObject['zone'];
    
    // if the zone exists in the zones[] defined above
    // add the current zone to its place
    //
    // if not (else), we have to add the array for the
    // current index, then add the value of the current zone.
    if(zones[index]) {
      zones[index]['zone' + (index + 1)].push(zone);
    } else {
      zones.push({ ['zone' + (index + 1)]: [zone]})
    }
  });
});
    
console.log(zones);
```